# AWS Graviton Processors: which encryption specs are hardware accelerated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, central-processing-unit, encryption, cryptography

In testing Graviton instances there seems to be significantly more CPU overhead from AES/SHA functions compared to the same on cheaper/smaller Intel/AMD instances. Do these procs supports hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 8):

While digging around for my question, I found a solution. Sources are hard to find, but quoting [a somewhat random 2018 news article](https://www.theregister.com/2018/11/27/amazon_aws_graviton_specs):

> Its CPU cores are based on Arm's 2015-era Cortex-A72 designs, and are clocked at 2.3GHz. They are 64-bit, Armv8-A, little endian, non-NUMA, and feature hardware acceleration for floating-point math, SIMD, plus AES, SHA-1, SHA-256, GCM, and CRC-32 algorithms.

With testing I found a theme common to other procs -- **perf greatly varies by generation**. At first I didn't consider **Graviton** vs **Graviton2** vs **Graviton3**, but they all support hardware acceleration at different levels. A quick test of `SHA-256` on 1MB - 32MB payloads per second (i.e. L2 and L3 cache, thanks [anandtech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xweAm.png)) shows 6+ GB/s for `16vCPU` classes of different Graviton generations.
[image: benchmark results]

Also tested lower `1vCPU` and `2vCPU` instances, but perf was inconsistent < 1GB/s. Unsure if resource sharing was affecting results.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very interesting article from the Arm team called [AWS Graviton3 delivers leading AES-GCM encryption performance](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/infrastructure-solutions-blog/posts/aes-gcm-optimizations-for-armv8-4-on-neoverse-v1-graviton3) where they shared this:

> Arm Neoverse platforms are now able to take advantage of the Cryptographic Extensions in Armv8-A to accelerate important cryptographic operations. This blog introduces the Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) of the popular Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm. And shows how to make the best use of these instructions and expose the full potential of Arm Neoverse platforms.

They shared a benchmark comparing the encryption performance between c6g, c7g, and c6i (3rd Gen Intel Xeon Scalable). Perhaps using the instructions there, we can know more about it, specifically about the [Cryptographic Extensions in Armv8-A cores](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0501/f/introduction/about-the-cortex-a53-processor-cryptography-extension)

The results of the benchmarks were very interesting:

> Overall, the performance of AES-GCM on c7g is around 100% higher than that on c6i. c6i achieves a higher performance when testing with one thread. However, it does not scale well with multiple threads. With hyperthreading on c6i, if one hyperthread executes AVX512 code, the core has to reduce its frequency, which slows down the execution on the sibling hyperthread of the same core. The performance on c6g is slightly lower than c6i, but it catches up with c6i on multi threads.
> [image: Performance comparison of aes-gcm with different numbers of threads between c6g, c6i and c7g and]

Comment: `AES128 threads=16`~`16vCPU` hits 60+GB/s, wow. That single Intel win on `threads=1` clears up what was going on with the cheap instances I tried. 

Hey Intel it's an ARMs race now! I'll show myself out.

Comment: oh and @marcosluis2186 in case the link breaks, consider inserting a copy of that aes-gcm threads vs throughput bar chart, that is a solid contribution

Comment: Let me update the comment